# Converting a Flash animation to Silverlight

Tags: xna, silverlight, compression

I recently had an animated logo done in Flash for Deen Games. I need to display in all my Silverlight games. The problem is, the logo is about ~8 seconds long (205 frames); if I export all the images as even JPEGs, the result is almost 3.5MB of content (more than the game itself).

I tried exporting as various formats (PNG, JPG, GIF, etc.) but nothing is small enough. What are my options? How can I incorporate these into my game without blowing up the file size?

There's always the option of "recreate it in-game with animation/rotation/etc. as it is now) but that's tons of work and I'd rather avoid that.

And no, just a static image is not good enough!

**Edit:** Exporting as a movie (AVI, MPEG) won't work since XNA doesn't support movies at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash SWFs are small because graphics are vector and only animation diffs are stored. What this means is that you should **recreate your animation in your platform.** Anything else will requier redundant storage and a huge file-size.

Answer (score 5):

You can export them as a series of images (I would recommend the highest quality you can), compress them into a video file and import the video file into Silverlight. I believe this will have a smaller size than the set of images, especially if you choose a good encoder (like [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html)).

Comment: This might become a problem if I go multi-platform tomorrow; Android is on my radar too.

Comment: "Playing a movie" is pretty multiplatform.

Comment: This still produces huge files, and XNA doesn't support movies at this time (unless I'm mistaken; I'm using SilverSprite).

Comment: I haven't played a video myself, but according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417503.aspx#ID4EIFAC XNA 4.0 supports video playback. A quick search revealed that video playback started at 3.1: http://www.google.com/search?q=xna video playback

Comment: The videos are 2-3mb. It's not worth it when my game is ~2MB.

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one application that claims to do this:

[SilverX](http://www.silverx.net/)

I haven't used this so I don't know how good or cost effective it is. However, as you've only got one animation to convert it might be good enough for a short term solution.